# Symfony 6.1 : issue after installation of bundle SymfonyCasts / reset-password-bundle

Tags: php, symfony

I installed this bundle in my symfony 6 project with composer, and I got this error message :

```
There is no extension able to load the configuration for "symfonycasts_reset_password" (in "myproject/config/packages/reset_password.yaml")
```

I tried to add this line in config/bundles.php

```
    SymfonyCasts\Bundle\ResetPassword\SymfonyCastsResetPasswordBundle::class => ['all' => true],
```

I tried this one too :

```
    SymfonyCasts\Bundle\ResetPassword\ResetPasswordBundle::class => ['all' => true],
```

and I got now this error :

```
Attempted to load class "SymfonyCastsResetPasswordBundle" from namespace "SymfonyCasts\Bundle\ResetPassword".
```

I don't know if it's a progress or not

I also tried a composer dump-autoload and The issue persist

the package is correctly installed, I saw it in my composer.json and when I launch the command "composer show", the package is in my vendor files, I can use the command make:reset-password

I have this in my reset_password.yml file in config/ packages :

```
symfonycasts_reset_password:
    request_password_repository: App\Repository\ResetPasswordRequestRepository
```

I don't know why I have this issue, someone can help me please ? thanks